# Can't weight paint certain parts of a mesh

Tags: weight-painting

No matter what I try I cant weight paint the legs of my mesh.
Here I have painted everything to display which parts can be painted to and which parts cant.
I've tried recreating the rig from scratch, I've gone through every single vertex in the mesh looking for any mistakes and I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong. No matter what I try I can't assign these parts of my mesh to the bones

[image: weight painting on model]

You can download the .blend file here  https://filetea.me/t1sKqtmxwS6TvKTj098L24KsQ

Comment: The link to the file doesn't seem to provide the file, opening only the empty page instead. Could you provide another preferably with using [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) ?

Comment: I would guess either reversed normals or an accidental mask.